# Set-uri in haproxy of an HTTP request

Tags: https, haproxy

I tried to change the uri of an incoming GET request to redirect it to a different URL.
What I did: 
backend
httprequest set-uri https://www.example.com/ping

The example url works directly, but I receive 503 for requests that are directed there from haproxy.

What seems to be wrong?

Comment: What exactly do yo want to do? you can use http-request redirect to redirect

Comment: I want the user to receive 200 instead of 302 as HTTP response and redirect it to another URL from backend

Answer (score 0):

You need to put 'server' directive after 'http-request' event if you rewrite the whole URL